# How to get the url of a .nupkg file?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I want to download some .nupkg files using my browser

In nuget.org, there are no links to the .nupkg file

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The URLs are typically in the format:

```
http://nuget.org/api/v2/package/PACKAGE_ID/VERSION
```

For example, for WebActivator:

```
http://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure/1.0.0.0
```

If you just want the latest version of the package, leave out the version number:

```
http://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure/
```

Comment: I wrote a Chrome extension that adds this link to the package page https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nutake/ibhhbcaipjilldjkhhblhgdedjgoecap?hl=en

Comment: NuGet.org has been having issues all week...Thanks this saved me lots of time and frustration! They provide a direct download link on the page.

Comment: above command downloads a zip with NUSPEC file, there is no NUPKG file in it

Answer (score 1):

You can link directly to the package file version using the below pattern.

```
https://globalcdn.nuget.org/packages/{package name}
```

For example:

```
https://globalcdn.nuget.org/packages/mono.cecil.0.11.5.nupkg
```