# Download Nuget Packages Without VS/NuGet Package Manager

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, repository

How can I download NuGet Packages outside of visual studio? so it can be used to create offline packages.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597375/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-nupkg-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a Nuget package without nuget.exe or Visual Studio extension? from nuget.org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894864/how-to-download-a-nuget-package-without-nuget-exe-or-visual-studio-extension-fr)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**How to download NuGet Package without Visual Studio or Nuget Package Manager:**

1. Search your desired package at [NuGet Official Site](http://packages.nuget.org/packages).
2. Copy the end of the URL of the package page. 
   For Example: http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework => Package Name is *"EntityFramework"*
3. Enter the URL: http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/**{Package Name}**
   For Example: http://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/EntityFramework

Comment: Just a note to anyone coming across this question, many years later. When the package downloads, just rename the extension to **`.zip`** as mentioned in the **[solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28183316/2333450)** by @Steve. Then when you open the file you will have all the files you need. Sadly I have to do this now, as my offices proxy seems to prevent the use of the Package Manager (Since I get asked for credentials, and my Nuget credentials do not work).

Comment: another note: the NuGet Gallery has a "Download Package" link on the right...

Answer (score 19):

You can download NuGet packages outside of Visual Studio using:

[NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/releases)

> NuGet Package Explorer is a ClickOnce application which allows
> creating and exploring NuGet packages easily. After installing it, you
> can double click on a .nupkg file to view the package content. You can
> also load packages directly from the official NuGet feed.

Open a package from online feed:

[image]

[image]

And export the package to the desired location:

[image]

Comment: This works best. Here is the current link to download this tool: http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/59864

Comment: @atconway This is now incorrect - I got the following message when I downloaded it from there: "...I have decided to move it permanently to http://npe.codeplex.com ..."

Comment: Too bad the link is dead

Answer (score 15):

[Install the NuGet command line program](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#installing):

> The NuGet command line may be installed onto a machine in a few possible ways.
>
> 1. Direct download of the executable from https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe. The executable may be placed anywhere on the file system, and in most cases should be placed in a directory that is listed in the PATH environment variable.
> 2. Install the NuGet.CommandLine package from the NuGet Visual Studio client and either move nuget.exe to a common location or execute it in the context of your project.
> 3. Install the NuGet.CommandLine Chocolatey package using the Chocolatey client. More information on Chocolatey can be found at [http://chocolatey.org].

Then run `nuget install package` to download and install `package` in the current directory.

More about the NuGet command line program:

- [Command Line Reference](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference)

Comment: The nuget.exe command-line tool will provide the most flexibility for scripting and automation.

Comment: Just recently I wrote a PowerShell Script to download Packages: https://bitbucket.org/theFil/nugetpackagefetcher/src/d44a5f0c2849e784293f63ffeb9207eaed242cf2/GetPackages.ps1?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Answer (score 3):

Chrome Plugin "NuTake" provides a direct download link.

Rename extension to .zip and extract

Answer (score 1):

You can download nuget packages using - [vnuget.org](http://vnuget.org).

On this website you can also view content of nuget package - http://vnuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.3.

Comment: Please remove this stale answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples that can add to DeePak's answer:

This one downloads AutoMapper from NuGet.org

```
nuget.exe install AutoMapper  -OutputDirectory c:\Temp\LotsOfPackages -Version 6.2.2
```

This one downloads MyCustomPackage from an internal TFS Nuget feed

```
nuget.exe install MyCustomPackage  -OutputDirectory c:\Temp\LotsOfPackages -Source "http://tfs.myCompany.com:8080/tfs/TFSArea/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v3/index.json" -Version 1.0.0.2
```

Notes

- Keep in mind that the install command will get the package in question AND all its NuGet dependencies.  So, be careful about just dumping this into the directory where you running.  Thus, I added OutputDirectory to the command.
- For internal Nuget packages/feeds, the Source URL is available via TFS.  Go to your packages tab and find your specific feed URL.  If it has any spaces that have been encoded with %20, you need to replace them with spaces.
- [CLI command reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install)
- [Copy packages from one NuGet feed to another](https://blog.myget.org/post/2011/07/15/copy-packages-from-one-nuget-feed-to-another.html)