# How to install the MS C# 6.0 compiler?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I am trying to compile a C# project that someone has created while using C# 6.0 features.

In previous .NET releases, the current C# compiler was automatically installed and ready to run along with the .NET Framework. Apparently, this is no longer the case. I currently have .NET 4.6.1 on my machine, but invoking `csc` tells me:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only
supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. Fo
r compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http
://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
```

The [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240) forwards me to the [Roslyn project on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). It does not seem to offer any binary releases.

Curiously, googling for `C# 6.0 compiler` brings up a couple of discussions on [how to add C# 6.0 support to Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093908/how-to-enable-c-sharp-6-0-feature-in-visual-studio-2013) (with the consensus being more or less that you can't), and countless articles presenting the (admittedly wonderful) new features of C# 6.0, but not a hint on how to obtain a compiler for C# 6.0.

So: **How can I get the MS C# 6.0 compiler, and, if required, the necessary build tools such as current versions of MSBuild?**

Note that I do not usually have Visual Studio installed, as [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) seems to be superior for my purposes, so I am wary of installing several gigabytes of data when I already have the framework just to get the up-to-date compiler.

Comment: So you just want the latest [MSBuild](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) tools?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007871/how-to-upgrade-msbuild-to-c-sharp-6

Comment: @DavidG: Oh, that's where it's hiding now? :-) Possibly, that's what I'm looking for, yes.

Comment: @Alan: While related, the other question starts after having installed VS 2015, whereas I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @F-H: From the accepted answer: "You can get this version of MsBuild on your system by installing any edition of Visual Studio 2015 or by installing the stand-alone Microsoft Build Tools 2015...Adding a reference to the following NuGet package will also force use of the new compiler:"

Comment: You just need to install the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/ which you can do [without Visual Studio installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482319/download-nuget-packages-without-vs-nuget-package-manager)

Comment: @F-H When you say "hiding", I got that link by Googling for it, it was the top link, that's not very hidden at all...

Comment: @DavidG: When I google for "C# 6.0 compiler", the first two results are inquiries on how to enable C# 6.0 in VS2013, followed by an article on what's great about C# 6.0, another text about VS2013 integration, a guide for migrating projects to C# 6.0, and so on. The penultimate result on page 1 is the Roslyn project page, where (as described in the question), it did not seem obvious to me how to find a binary release. After a couple of more articles on new C# 6.0 language features, I finally get a search result to the first actual compiler release - the one on mono-project.com.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the Roslyn project on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn#download-c-and-visual-basic):

> To install the latest release without Visual Studio, run one of the following nuget command lines:
>
> ```
> nuget install Microsoft.Net.Compilers   # Install C# and VB compilers
> nuget install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis    # Install Language APIs and Services
> ```
>
> To get the latest "preview" drop, published about once per month, add the `-pre` switch to the nuget commands.

Comment: Use 4 spaces at the beginning of a line to format it as code/commands :)

Comment: And if you are going to quote material from another site word for word (which is the case here), make sure to give proper attribution.

Comment: Excellent, this sounds helpful. I guess Github is trying to train us to accept a readme file from source control as a website substitute to be read before finding a release, rather than the other way round ;)