# Build Error -- Selenium -- Cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a code that works in other computer, but when I tried to build in mine, I had error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1528  Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in
>   declaration)"

```
protected IWebElement GetElementByCssSelector(string selector, int? timeout = null, bool useTimeout = true)
{
        IWebElement GetElement() => Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));  // LINE WITH ERROR //

        if (!useTimeout) 
           return GetElement();

        timeout = timeout ?? defaultTimeout;

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout.Value));
        wait.Until(x => GetElement().Displayed);

        return GetElement();
}
```

I already tried to update the references and it didn´t work.

Comment: What visual studio are you using?

Comment: @Guy 
Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Comment: Did you enable C# 6 for the project?

Comment: Yes. Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968963/c-sharp-6-0-features-not-working-with-visual-studio-2015/31548221) will help. By the way, did you try restarting VS?

Comment: I restarted, and I already set C# 6.
I already tried CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler.
Nothing :(

Comment: Well, your settings looks ok as far as I know. Perhaps you can roll back and [reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39090109/5168011) the updates?